# select with multiple values in an insert statement using PG gem with Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, pg

Can you guys help me out with this.
If I use this db query directly in the postgresql database it works fine, however when using the PG gem in Ruby it expects me to have 6 values in the array, however I want to get those values from a SELECT statement.

The error message that I'm getting is:

```
ERROR:  bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "statement2" requires 6 (PG::ProtocolViolation)
```

Here's the code in Ruby using PG gem.

```
conn.prepare('statement2', 'INSERT INTO client_results (client_type, distance, hostname, serial_number, rssi, txrate) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)')
conn.exec_prepared('statement2', ["SELECT client_type, distance_in_ft, hostname, serial_number, -65, 224 FROM test_clients WHERE eth_ipv4 = 192.168.0.1"])
```

The actual SQL that works looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO client_results (client_type, distance, hostname, serial_number, rssi, txrate) SELECT client_type, distance_in_ft, hostname, serial_number, -65, 224 FROM test_clients WHERE eth_ipv4 = '192.168.0.1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = conn.exec("SELECT client_type, distance_in_ft, hostname, serial_number, -65, 224 FROM test_clients WHERE eth_ipv4 = 192.168.0.1").first

conn.prepare('statement2', 'INSERT INTO client_results (client_type, distance, hostname, serial_number, rssi, txrate) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)')
conn.exec_prepared('statement2', res.values)
```

or simply run the query as is:

```
conn.exec("INSERT INTO client_results (client_type, distance, hostname, serial_number, rssi, txrate) SELECT client_type, distance_in_ft, hostname, serial_number, -65, 224 FROM test_clients WHERE eth_ipv4 = '192.168.0.1'")
```

Comment: Thanks, running the simple query with conn.exec worked fine, however when trying the separate conn_prepare options, the error message that I would get was that it would supply 5 parameters instead of 6 even though I checked several times that the parameters were 6. Manually checking the "res" array would show that the '-65' value was missing and I don't understand why.